# Can't find gke metrics workload

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I found the new gke metrics Workload as a really interesting option for testing prometheus outputs from custom endpoints.

I configured my gke cluster, in 1.21.5-gke.1302 to use WORKLOADS in the monitoring_configuration and it created all the necessary pods on the cluster kube-admin namespace. I also have the podmonitor resource available in kubernetes that appears to be ready.

But when I go in stackdriver metrics explorer I can't seems to see my metrics in it. I tried to go in Resource type "Kubernetes Container" but I can't find any "workload.googleapis.com/". It's been running for one hour and I can't find the metrics.

Did anyone managed to get metrics from the service?

Comment: Can you post your PodMonitor YAML?  I've used the feature multiple times successfully.  You can check the first few steps of https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/workload-metrics-autoscaling to see if what you are doing matches.  The last few steps configure autoscaling (which I don't think you are trying to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so we finally found the issue. It was a typo in the pod port name, but as everything else was working before we didn't thought of looking there when we added the podmonitor.

With the fix on the port name, it seems to work even if it glitches sometimes for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I just played with this today.

First check with [gcloud beta container clusters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/clusters) describe to see if your cluster thinks it should collect workload metrics too. You should find "WORKLOADS" in the enabled metrics components section.

```
gcloud beta container clusters describe example-cluster --zone chosen-zone
```

If this is enabled go through the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/managing-metrics#requirements) to see what you missed during enabling it.

Comment: Hello, as I said in the post, it doesn't seem like I missed anything, the service is enabled and I already did go through the doc... and the debug parts to no avail.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, workload metrics is not a production-ready feature yet. If you have a support package try opening a ticket a see if support is willing to help with this. I'm not sure what else you could try.
https://cloud.google.com/support-hub